# > Could not initialize class com.android.repository.api.RepoManager

Tags: java, android-studio, apk, android-app-bundle

I  am new in Android Studio. After setup, When I am trying to import an application I am getting that error So that gradle not able to build.

**Error:> Could not initialize class com.android.repository.api.RepoManager**

I checked that my classpath setting for Java is fine. I am running Windows OS. Does anyone know the source of the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue while trying to run a 5-year-old android project. Following these steps fixed the issue for me:

1- update gradle version in the project level build.gradle file  from

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'` 
to

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'`

2- add google() to the project repositories

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
}}
```

and in buildScript block as well:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
} dependencies {...}}
```

3- update gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties file to an up-to-date version, I updated to 7.2

4- In the app level build.gradle file, in the dependencies block, I changed `compile` to `implementation`

5- sync the project

Comment: This should be marked as answer, for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with Android studio. Use some other version of android studio  https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/

Answer (score -1):

A downgrade to `Android Studio 4.0` fixed the error for me.

Comment: Android Studio maintains backward compatibility with most of the legacy code